# Customization of Virtual Machine at time of creation(cloning) using VSphere SDK 6.0 Java application

Tags: java, virtual-machine, vsphere

I'm working on Virtual Machine provisioning using VSphere SDK 6.0. I have succeeded in provisioning the virtual machine from template using the following method

```
ManagedObjectReference cloneTask =
                vimPort.cloneVMTask(vmRef, vmFolderRef, cloneName, cloneSpec);
```

I have also got the customization of **Memory, CPU** with the following method.

```
 VirtualMachineConfigSpec configSpec = new VirtualMachineConfigSpec();
        configSpec.setMemoryMB(512l);
        configSpec.setNumCPUs(2);
```

I want to know more customization using the SDK like **HarkDisk, N/W Adapter, Networking** details etc. Help me to get some java code samples with the customization of the virtual machine or get me some links mentioning about the same. Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

To add disks and a network adapter you need to create a VirtualDeviceConfigSpec.
after you create a complete virtualdeviceconfigspec, you use:
VirtualMachineConfigSpec.DeviceChange = yourdeviceconfigspec;

This code is pseudo-c# but close enough to Java to get the idea.  Then you use the config spec in the clone/creation.

Here is a c# function to add 3 paravirtual controllers and 5 disks, all bundled up into a List

```
        public List<VirtualDeviceConfigSpec> Add_Disks(int numberofDisks, ManagedObjectReference dsMoref, VimClient vsphere, string vmname, string dsname)
    {
        List<int> diskSize = new List<int> { 20000, 10000, 20000, 10000, 20000 };
        List<VirtualDeviceConfigSpec> specs = new List<VirtualDeviceConfigSpec>();

        //Add Three Paravirtual Controllers
        VirtualDeviceConfigSpec para1 = new VirtualDeviceConfigSpec();
        ParaVirtualSCSIController p1 = new ParaVirtualSCSIController();
        p1.Key = 1;
        p1.SharedBus = VirtualSCSISharing.noSharing;
        p1.BusNumber = 1;
        p1.HotAddRemove = true;
        para1.Device = p1;
        para1.Operation = VirtualDeviceConfigSpecOperation.add;
        specs.Add(para1);

        VirtualDeviceConfigSpec para2 = new VirtualDeviceConfigSpec();
        ParaVirtualSCSIController p2 = new ParaVirtualSCSIController();
        p2.Key = 2;
        p2.SharedBus = VirtualSCSISharing.noSharing;
        p2.BusNumber = 2;
        p2.HotAddRemove = true;
        para2.Device = p2;
        para2.Operation = VirtualDeviceConfigSpecOperation.add;
        specs.Add(para2);

        VirtualDeviceConfigSpec para3 = new VirtualDeviceConfigSpec();
        ParaVirtualSCSIController p3 = new ParaVirtualSCSIController();
        p3.Key = 3;
        p3.SharedBus = VirtualSCSISharing.noSharing;
        p3.BusNumber = 3;
        p3.HotAddRemove = true;
        para3.Device = p3;
        para3.Operation = VirtualDeviceConfigSpecOperation.add;
        specs.Add(para3);

        for (int i = 0; i < diskSize.Count; i++)
        {
            //set up standard disks specs
            bool thinProvisioned = true;
            int size = (diskSize[i]);
            int controllerKey = 0;
            int unitNumber = 0;

            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    controllerKey = 1;
                    unitNumber = 0;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    controllerKey = 3;
                    unitNumber = 0;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    controllerKey = 2;
                    unitNumber = 0;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    controllerKey = 2;
                    unitNumber = 1;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    controllerKey = 3;
                    unitNumber = 1;
                    break;
            }

            VirtualDiskFlatVer2BackingInfo backInfo = new VirtualDiskFlatVer2BackingInfo();
            backInfo.ThinProvisioned = thinProvisioned;
            backInfo.DiskMode = "persistent";
            backInfo.Datastore = dsMoref;
            backInfo.FileName = "[" + dsname + "]" + vmname + "/" + vmname + controllerKey + "_" + unitNumber + ".vmdk";

            VirtualDisk tempDisk = new VirtualDisk();
            tempDisk.Backing = backInfo;
            tempDisk.CapacityInKB = (1024 * size);
            tempDisk.ControllerKey = controllerKey;
            tempDisk.Key = (1 + i);
            tempDisk.UnitNumber = unitNumber;

            VirtualDeviceConfigSpec tempConfigSpec = new VirtualDeviceConfigSpec();
            tempConfigSpec.Device = tempDisk;
            tempConfigSpec.FileOperation = VirtualDeviceConfigSpecFileOperation.create;
            tempConfigSpec.Operation = VirtualDeviceConfigSpecOperation.add;

            specs.Add(tempConfigSpec);
        }

        return specs;
    }
```